# How to save time correctly so that it can be edited later

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, jodatime, simpledateformat

I have had trouble saving time for some time. Maybe I will first describe how I would like it to work. The application saves time during several events, subtracts or adds these values in this way counting the time spent e.g. at work or on any activity. Time is saved to Firebase - for this reason it is saved as timeinmilis -> Long. I would also like to be able to edit the time, so I download the time, and change it freely using the timepicker or datapicker to choose start and end activities. After selecting the beginning and end I calculate the time and the problem is giving me time zone, using var timezone = 0L internal var zone = Calendar.getInstance (). TimeZone.getOffset (timezone) I tried to deal with this problem, to no avail. Is there a right way to write and perform mathematical operations (mainly adding and subtracting) in the language of kotlin?

i heard about jodatime but i didn't find anything about joda in kotlin .......

Comment: Since you are doing so much work with time, consider getting a good library for that. If for Andoird under API level 26 this typically means [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), the Andorid backport of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). This will make the calculations simpler and more natural and will make it straightforward to store [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted text to Firebase, which is human readable.

Comment: Using java.time will of course allow you to throw `Calendar`, `TimeZone` and `SimpleDateFormat` over your shoulder, which is good because those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the last in particular notoriously troublesome. java.time is the successor of Joda-Time and generally considered even better.